# Why isn't the addremove recommended by default in Mercurial?

Tags: version-control, mercurial

This is perhaps a question of strategy more than anything else. I am new to version control and I guess I should count myself lucky to have relatively more mature systems like `Mercurial` and `Git` at my disposal as compared to the older systems.

I started with `Hg` because I read somewhere that it's more `Python`like in its approach. The few tutorials that I went through (examples and videos) consistently use the command `hg add *`. After using that command for some time now on my project, I have a long list of files which have `!` in front of the files that have been deleted. I am speaking of the output of the command `hg st` of course.

I guess using `hg addremove *` will solve my problem. If that's the case, why isn't it the default command to teach `Hg` to a beginner? Is there a pitfall I am missing? Wouldn't it be reasonable to assume that typically a person working on a folder would want the files which are deleted to visibly disappear from the output of `hg st` (esp. since they are stored in the repository by `Hg` anyways)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`hg add *` is a terribly idea. The tutorials you've read/watched probably weren't very good. Most repositories contain many files that you don't want to put under version control: Generated artifacts, junk from experiments you did, and files that should be part of the repository but only *later* (i.e., are not ready to be committed). You don't want to version control those. Unless they are only temporary, they should be listed in `.hgignore` so they won't pollute the output of `hg status` with `?`s and won't be added accidentally. `hg add` and `hg addremove` already consider all files, *except ignored ones*, and `hg add *` and `hg addremove *` *override* this sane default. So it's not only redundant, but also breaks a very useful feature.

You should only add the files that make sense of have under version control. Then files "suddenly disappearing" is not a problem, because the only files Mercurial tracks are the important ones, which you rarely remove, and if so, only manually after careful consideration. In that case, use `hg rm file1 file2` to remove those files both from the file system and from mercurial — no need for `addremove`.

`hg addremove` is a useful shorthand if you screwed up and made significant changes to the project layout via some tool other than Mercurial, especially since it properly handles copies/renames. Note that you can restrict it to some files by giving, for example, `hg addremove src/`. But it should never override good judgement of what belongs under source control and what doesn't. If you accidentally added a file that shouldn't be under source control, use `hg forget the-file` before committing.

Comment: Even though I accepted your answer a week ago, I have fully realized the extent of my error just yet. My repo size is unnecessarily high. Of course I will correct this when I start fresh on my other projects, but what would be a good way to make repairs on my current repo? Should I untrack all files and then just add the ones I really need to follow?

Comment: @ShashankSawant Tough place to be in. You should certainly throw out files that have no reason to be tracked so the future looks brighter, but the history would still be a mess. If you care about repo size and a clean history, you could create a new repository and replay a cleaned-up version of history (same commits at the same date/time, omitting pointless files), but automating this is beyond my expertise and doing it manually is probably too much work and too error-prone. Maybe ask a new question?

Comment: Related question: https://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/276132/what-is-a-good-way-in-mercurial-to-untrack-all-files-and-start-fresh